# Getting inputs with scanf for an array

Tags: arrays, c, scanf, sizeof

Just getting to learn C better and I'm playing with arrays.

I would like to enter my phone number into an array like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{

    int phoneNum[10];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(phoneNum); i++) {
        printf("Insert digit %d of your phone number: \n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &phoneNum[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This seems to fail as it keeps asking me for a new digit. So I tried to print the size of the array:

```
int phoneNum[10];
printf("%lu", sizeof(phoneNum));
```

which incredibly gives me the result of 40 even though I initialized it to be 10 (?).
I have three questions:

1. Why is the result 40 and not 10 in `sizeof(phoneNum)` ?
2. How can I add elements in an array successfully with `scanf` in the above manner?
3. If the above manner is silly, is there a better, more efficient way to do this? For example directly enter 10 digits into an array? I can of course use `scanf("%d%d%d...", digit1, digit2, digit3, ...)` but I would like a generalized way, using the size of the array (say I don't know it and it's passed from another function)

Comment: Check this link out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c

Comment: Any particular reason you're failing to check the return value from `scanf()` to be sure it actually reads data before you loop to the next element?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I simply desire to understand this between arrays. The optimization part is another journey which is irrelevant for this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `sizeof(phoneNum)` returns 10 * sizeof(int). The sizeof(int) value appears to be 4 for your system.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>   

  int main() 
  {    

   int phoneNum[10] = {0};
   const size_t size = sizeof(phoneNum) / sizeof(int);

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       printf("Insert digit %d of your phone number: \n", i + 1);
       scanf("%d", &phoneNum[i]);
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
   {
       printf("\r\n %i \n", phoneNum[i]);
   }
   return 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(phoneNum)` will return number in bytes, not length of array.
after the `includes` you could make a define like `#define SIZE 10` and use `SIZE` like if it was a constant.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main()
{
    int phoneNum[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Take into account the fact that strings should end with [null terminated character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20a%20null,called%20NUL%20in%20this%20article) (`\0`) so the size of the string have that space available.